# Awk csv treatment output malformed line to stderr

Tags: awk, csv

I have a script that takes several CSV files from a folder and puts them together in a gzip file with one field extracted from the file name :

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }
FNR == 1 { match(FILENAME, "([0-9]{8})", a); JOBID = a[1]; print $0, JOBID }
FNR > 1 { print $0, JOBID }' Event_*txt | gzip > agzipfile.gz
```

My goal is to use `NF` to check if the line contains 5 fields and if not print this line to stderr or to another file.
But I didn't understand or find a proper way of doing this.
Is it possible and how ?
PS: I'm using GNU `awk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect inside AWK:

```
NF != 5 { print > "/dev/stderr"; next }
```

`/dev/stderr` is one of the special filenames which GNU AWK processes internally. (Other AWK implementations will write to `/dev/stderr`, if possible; in many systems that’s connected to standard error anyway, so the result is the same.)

See [this section of the manual on redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#Redirection), and [this one on special file descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Special-FD.html#Special-FD).